# PDFLATEX didnt run

Tags: pdftex

```
enter code here



    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
             restricted \write18 enabled.
            entering extended mode
            (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..tex
            LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
            Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
            Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
            Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
            (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..spl)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
            (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
            [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
            ) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
            (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
            (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..out) (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..out)`enter code here
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Tessor2006' on page 1 undefined on input line
 30.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Kim2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 30
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2016' on page 1 undefined on input line 30.



Overfull \hbox (5.36177pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--35
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Design/methodology/approach-The re-search pop-u-la-tion con-sis
ts of the cus-tomers

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 28--35

[1{c:/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Tsaur2006' on page 2 undefined on input line 
44.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Solomon2012' on page 2 undefined on input lin
e 59.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 42--73

[2] (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Schmitt1999' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 78.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `liou2011' on page 3 undefined on input line 8
0.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `liou2011' on page 3 undefined on input line 8
3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Schmitt1999' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 85.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `lee2012' on page 3 undefined on input line 87
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Schmitt1999' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 88.


Overfull \hbox (41.45905pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 75--95
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 counter with the prod-uct, fa-cil-ity or ser-vice that is be-in
g pro-moted(Schmitt,1999)/[\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 75--95

[3]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `chao2015' on page 4 undefined on input line 9
7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `lee2012' on page 4 undefined on input line 97
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Smilanski2009' on page 4 undefined on input l
ine 100.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Guest1994' on page 4 undefined on input line 
102.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Guest1995' on page 4 undefined on input line 
103.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Oliver1980' on page 4 undefined on input line
 104.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dick1994' on page 4 undefined on input line 1
04.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 95--109

[4]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Cowie2001' on page 5 undefined on input line 
113.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 109--116


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Solomon2012' on page 5 undefined on input lin
e 118.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 116--134

[5]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `kotler2010' on page 6 undefined on input line
 141.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Anton1996' on page 6 undefined on input line 
144.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Pine1999' on page 6 undefined on input line 1
44.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2014' on page 6 undefined on input line 149
.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 134--150


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Richins1997' on page 6 undefined on input lin
e 151.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `chaudhuri2001' on page 6 undefined on input l
ine 152.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Lotz1999' on page 6 undefined on input line 1
53.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `chaudhuri2001' on page 6 undefined on input l
ine 154.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Tsaur2006' on page 6 undefined on input line 
156.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Saeednia2013' on page 6 undefined on input li
ne 157.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Liljander1999' on page 6 undefined on input l
ine 158.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Bloch1994' on page 6 undefined on input line 
158.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Saeednia2013' on page 6 undefined on input li
ne 159.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `chao2015' on page 6 undefined on input line 1
65.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2014' on page 6 undefined on input line 165
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ozturk2015' on page 6 undefined on input line
 166.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2014' on page 6 undefined on input line 166
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Oliver1980' on page 6 undefined on input line
 169.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2016' on page 6 undefined on input line 170
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Burns2006' on page 6 undefined on input line 
172.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ming2010' on page 6 undefined on input line 1
72.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2014' on page 6 undefined on input line 172
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Jayawardhena2009' on page 6 undefined on inpu
t line 176.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Liang2012' on page 6 undefined on input line 
180.


Overfull \hbox (33.95901pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 150--185
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 also the de-ter-mi-nant fac-tors in choos-ing ser-vices and pro
d-ucts(Chaudhuri,2001)/[\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?

Overfull \hbox (42.65352pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 150--185
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 plea-sure and stim-u-la-tion) can cre-ate pos-i-tive loy-alty,(
Liljander&Bergenwall,1999)/[\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ?

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 150--185

[6] [7]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Tsaur2006' on page 8 undefined on input line 
201.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Kim2006' on page 8 undefined on input line 20
1.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2016' on page 8 undefined on input line 202
.

[8] [9]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Hair2013' on page 10 undefined on input line 
236.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Hulland1999' on page 10 undefined on input li
ne 283.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Henseler2009' on page 10 undefined on input l
ine 318.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `chao2015' on page 10 undefined on input line 
413.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ozturk2015' on page 10 undefined on input lin
e 413.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wu2014' on page 10 undefined on input line 41
3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Park2015' on page 10 undefined on input line 
413.


LaTeX Warning: File `figure/aks smr.png' not found on input line 439.

[10] [11] [12] [13] [14]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Krishna2014' on page 15 undefined on input li
ne 466.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Maghsoudi2016' on page 15 undefined on input 
line 472.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Maghsoudi2016' on page 15 undefined on input 
line 476.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Krishna2014' on page 15 undefined on input li
ne 478.

[15] [16 <./figure/aks smr.png>] [17] [18]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 526--533

[19] (./elsarticle-template-last SMR..bbl
Underfull \hbox (badness 1184) in paragraph at lines 4--8
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Anton, J. [1996], \OT1/cmr/m/it/10 Cus-tomer re-la-tion-ship 
man-age-ment: Mak-ing hard

Overfull \hbox (59.3476pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--8
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 URL: \OT1/cmr/m/it/10 https://search.proquest.com/openview/e4a
1e9a0d90dfef0584367379ec23090/1?pq-
[20]
Overfull \hbox (190.85785pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 33--37
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 URL: \OT1/cmr/m/it/10 http://ezproxy.uow.edu.au/login?url=http
://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=s3h&AN=SPHS-

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character － (U+FF0D)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.48   Squares Structural Equation Modeling(PLS－
                                                  SEM)}}.
?
```

here are my lines:
p.s. except for bib file the other one, it was just written "end of the document" when I tried to open them to read. What is the problem?tnx

```
     \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
        \usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{graphics}
        \usepackage{adjustbox}
        \journal{Sport Management Review}
        \modulolinenumbers[5]
        %% Elsevier bibliography styles
        %% Vancouver numbered
        %\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
        %% Vancouver name/year
        %\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
        %% APA style
        %\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
        %% AMA style
        %\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}
        %% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
        \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{The impact of Experiential Marketing on Customer Loyalty for Sports Brands (The moderating effect of values and lifestyles) \tnoteref{}} 

   \begin{abstract}`enter code here
    ...
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{keyword}
    Experiential marketing, loyalty, satisfaction, excitement, values and lifestyles.
    \end{keyword}
    \end{frontmatter}
    \linenumbers
    \section{Introduction}
        ...
    \section{Literature review}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Experiential marketing\\
    ...
    \item Excitement\\
    ...
    \end{itemize}
    \section{Methodology}
    ...
    \section{results}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Describing demographic characteristics of sample\\
    ...
    \item Data analysis
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Validity and reliability of the variables}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \hline
    Variables&AVE&CR&Cronbach 's alpha\\
    \hline
    Excitement&0.827800&0.935145&0.896023\\
    Satisfaction&0.679943&0.863718&0.763434\\
    Loyalty&0.686115&0.864091&0.763485\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    ...
    \begin {figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/aks smr.png}
    \caption{Testing model results}
    \end{figure}
    \end{itemize}
    \section{findings}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Practical implication\\
    ...
    \section{ Research limitations}
    ...
    \end{itemize}
    \section{Implication for future studies}
    ...
    \section*{References}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm} 
    \bibliography{c:/users/pars/desktop/SMRARTICLE}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code so that it looks how you want it to look?  I assume that `enter code here` is an artifact of inputting into TeX.SE, and not something in your code.  And I'm not sure what you mean by "pdflatex didn't run", since that log file looks like it ran, although possibly not successfully.  What did happen?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point by" an artifact of inputting into TeX.SE, & not sth. in my code" ? English is not my first language, would u kindly explain a little more? I tried to run this LaTeX but in the third run (PDFLATEX) the bottom was red and didn't run. tnx @Teepeemm

Comment: Your sample code contains `\begin{frontmatter}` and `\begin{abstract}` statements but no `\end{frontmatter}` and `\end{abstract}` statements

Comment: The excerpt from the `.log` you posted is not a complete `.log` file and does not show any obvious errors. Please copy and paste the *complete* `.log` file.

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't think one should have to use ```\\``` in an `itemize`. Maybe you want a `description` instead: `\begin{description}\item[Experiential marketing] lorem ipsum \item[Excitement] dolor sit amet\end{description}`

Comment: After correcting your document example now is missing `\begin{table}` Adding them, your document is compilable without errors. Also package `hyperref` should be loaded last in preamble.

Comment: You have three occurrences of "enter code here" that I don't think are in the code on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character － (U+FF0D)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Unfortunately, this part of your document does not appear in your question. For another question, you might want to consider reading about [minimal working examples (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

However, `U+FF0D` is a [full width hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0d/index.htm): －

Just find that character in your TeX file and replace it, either by a `-` or by a `--`. You can copy the character above in order to search your document.

Comment: More specifically, it appears that it is in `Squares Structural Equation Modeling(PLS-SEM)`.  Very likely, you copy/pasted that hyphen into your document, so that your editor pasted something that looks like a hyphen but isn't quite.  Delete and retype that character.

Comment: Thank u. but I could find (PLS-SEM) in the context to omit hyphen , it is written 1.48, is that the error line number in the content? @Teepeemm

Comment: @Sarah Yes, L.48 refers to line 48.  Unfortunately, it might be line 48 in some other file that TeX generated.  You would do better to search through your bibliography for the phrase "Squares Structural Equation Modeling".

Comment: @sarah Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer, if it solved your problem. This way, the question does not remain "open" .

Comment: thank you very much I thought the problem is in Tex, and I couldn't find (PLS-SEM) especially in line 48 in the text, now I found that I have this HYPEN in my Bib file. thank u @Teepeemm

Comment: thank you very much for the help@PhilippImhof